# How to overwrite specific URLs to skip folder from path

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have WordPress installed in the folder **/blog**

I need to have a specific page that is part of that WordPress but which should not contain the segment /blog in the URL.

For example:
All my blog pages should be **www.domain.com/blog/page-name**

My Terms and Conditions page should be **www.domain.com/terms-and-conditions**

All the solutions I've found were affecting all my /blog/.. pages.
I just need a special condition for one specific page.

Comment: Can't you just install wp in your root folder and make blog the slug for your posts page? You can add 'newpage' as a subpage of blog to create /blog/newpage

Comment: That's not the solution I'm looking for.
There's an easier way using a RewriteRule in .htaccess

Comment: @SorinHaidau I have provided a solution using .htaccess and proxypass. Kindly have a look over it. If that solves your problem accept the solution otherwise do leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to internally pass the request to the Wordpress blog page.
This can be done through **.htaccess** and **mod_proxy**

your .htaccess file should contain

```
ProxyPass "/terms-and-conditions"  "http://www.example.com/blog/terms-and-conditions"
ProxyPassReverse "/terms-and-conditions"  "http://www.example.com/blog/terms-and-conditions"
```

Proxypass directive internally sent request as a proxy request.

Similar result can be expected from **RewriteEngine** using `[P]` flag like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "terms-and-conditions"  "http://www.example.com/blog/terms-and-conditions" [P]
```

Online example for the same is at [.htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=fa835f14-f560-54ee-814e-82825e888e99)

Comment: This generated a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @SorinHaidau, please try using the rewrite engine. Does http://www.example.com/blog/terms-and-conditions is working? Also change example.com to your domain.Let me know it that helps